# Xamarin forms fonts are missing using testflight

Tags: xamarin.forms, fonts, testflight

I used to distribute an iOS Xamarin Form Application on testflight.
I had to update my Windows Visual Studio to v16.11.6

Since this new version, the app il not working fine on iOS: all custom fonts are not loaded when the app is opened from testflight
But the problem is not there when using the simulator or deploying the app from visual studio on my iPhone

Could you help me

Comment: Add to your question: 1) In solution folder, what folder are the custom fonts in? Either a picture showing that part of the solution folder pane, or say in text what folder, including which project name. Something like MyProjectName / Media, or MyProjectName.iOS / Media. 2) What is the “Build Action” on each font? 3) What is the “ResourceId” or “ResourcePath” for one font? 4) Also add the line of xaml or c# that references one font - in your code where you use the font. 5) Breakpoint at that line in 4, what is the complete string being passed in to access the font?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.